# django i18n doesn't work in mac

Tags: django

I am using Mac High Sierra and I receive this error:

> CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
>   msguniq: Cannot convert from "ASCII" to "UTF-8". msguniq relies on iconv(). This version was built without iconv().

I've already tried with brew install gettext & force options.
I get the same error with anaconda.

Comment: Solution is to set path of homebrew based install i.e in my case is export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Worked for me, if you set this as the accepted answer, I can upvote it!

Answer (score 2):

You should add `gettext` executive path to global `PATH`.
If `gettext` has been installed in `/usr/local/opt/gettext`, so quick solution would be exporting following line in terminal:

```
PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"
```

If you don't know where `gettext` is located, run:

```
brew info gettext
```

And as the result of this command, you may find something like the following which in my case is:

> ...
>   If you need to have gettext first in your PATH run:
>       `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
>
> For compilers to find gettext you may need to set:
>     `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib"`
>     `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include"`
>   ...